how to send a fetch request for getting new data after the mutation request gets done nuxt apollo
I'm sending a mutation request for adding new product to my API in nuxt 3 app like this:
<script setup>
const myProducts = ref([]);
const addNewProductData= ref({id:1,name:'test'});
const isLoading = ref(false);
const total=ref(1);

const getAllQuery = gql`
        query fetchProducts{
          FetchProductPagination(
          page:1,
          limit:10,
        ){
          total
          data{
              id
              name
          }
        }
      }
 `;
 const fetchProducts = async () => {
  isLoading.value = true;
  const { data, error } = await useAsyncQuery(getAllQuery, null, "product");
  if (data.value) {
    myProducts.value = data.value.FetchProductPagination.data;
    total.value = data.value.FetchProductPagination.total;
  }
  isLoading.value = false;
};

const onSubmitAddProduct= async () => {
const query = gql`
  mutation AddProduct{
    AddProduct(
      id:${JSON.stringify(addNewProductData.id)},
      name: ${JSON.stringify(addNewProductData.name)}
    ) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;
  const { mutate, onDone } = await useMutation(query, { clientId: "product" });

  mutate();

  onDone(() => {
    fetchProducts()
  });
};


</script>

<template> <button @click="onSubmitAddProduct">add</button> </template>

as you see in onDone method I'm calling my fetchProducts function so I can have my new data from the API that has just been added, but the new fetch request doesn't send (i check it in network tab of browser) and my old data is still visible, while my function is called but its request doesn't get sent
I'm a newbie to Graphql, and I couldn't find any appropriate answer, so what is the problem, and why the new fetch request not sent?

Shouldn't you watch the onDone and fetch your products? Maybe it's a cache problem?

@kissu fetchProducts gets called but its fetch request not send i.e oeDone work as expected, what if it is cache? how can I solve it?

Ask it to make the query without the cache as written in the docs. Btw, what's useAsyncQuery?

would you please provide me a link from the doc I cant find it, useAsyncQuery is wrapper of useAsyncDataof nuxt which nuxt-apollo suggesting it in doc

Here for the cache, or any other GraphQL documentation. I would rather use useQuery, safer in terms of behavior, give it a try.

It calls mutate like me, I have several clients and with useQuery I can't find a way to set client for it, so I had to use useAysncQuery that nuxt-apollo was suggested

It was the cache problem, so i modify onSubmitAddProduct function like below and the problem solved
const onSubmitAddProduct = async () => {
  const query = gql`
  mutation AddProduct{
    AddProduct(
      id:${JSON.stringify(addNewProductData.id)},
      name: ${JSON.stringify(addNewProductData.name)}
    ) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;
  const { mutate } = await useMutation(query, { clientId: "product" });

  await mutate();

  await apollo.clients.product.cache.reset().then(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  });
};


You're welcome. Prefer using a global config for your Nuxt project.
